# Constructing a graph from a city in Python using Overpass

Tags: python, openstreetmap, routing, overpass-api, graph

I'm looking to construct something exactly like this person
[Building a graph from OSM?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104452/building-a-graph-from-osm)

That is I need to construct a graph with intersections as nodes and roads as edges for a simulation. Unlike this user I am doing this in Python and not PostgreSQL.

I assume I am going to need to use the Overpass Python API to get this data but I have never worked with this API before. I am competent enough in Python that as long as I can figure out how to request this data I will be fine.

However, I cant find any intuitive examples on how to retrieve this data in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving data from Overpass API using Python is very simple. Although you can use the Overpass API Python Wrapper, using `requests` is as easy. All you have to do is create an Overpass query and use `requests` to get it.

The following snippet shows how to retrieve all cities in Switzerland, read them as JSON and store them in a `pandas` DataFrame for further processing.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'  # Overpass API URL
query = f"""
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="CH"][admin_level=2];
node ["place"="city"](area);
out;
"""
r = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})
data = r.json()['elements']  # read response as JSON and get the data
df = json_normalize(data)  # create a DataFrame from the data
```

You can customize your queries to get different type of OSM data in different areas. For example you can specify a Bounding Box and retrieve specific amenties for that area. The following query will retrieve all the fuel stations in the Honolulu area.

```
query = f"""
    [out:json];
    node ["amenity"="fuel"]
    (21.215460, -157.956619, 21.385951, -157.724533);
    out;
"""
r = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})
```

[Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) is a great place to create queries which you can then copy to a python program. Check their query assistant.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this comes way too late, but it might be helpful for someone else finding this thread. If you want to extract from an `*.osm` file a graph then maybe you find this project helpful: https://github.com/AndGem/OsmToRoadGraph

What it does is, it reads an XML OSM file (for example from http://download.geofabrik.de/) and creates two files. One containing the graph data structure in a fairly simple format, and a second file containing street names.

Hope it helps someone,

Andreas